# Merging two columns with two values

Tags: r

I have columns which I know there name and that their data are 0 and 1.

I would like to merge them to one but if in one row exist the 1 take the one value or if I have 1 and 1 keep 1.

Example of data:

```
stockI stockII
    1   0
    1   0
    0   0
    0   0
    0   0
    0   0
    0   0
    1   0
    0   0
    1   1
```

the output I could expect:

```
stockI/stockII
    0   
    1   
    0   
    0   
    0   
    0   
    0   
    0   
    0   
    1
```

Is there any `cbind` method to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
as.integer(with(df1, (c(FALSE,stockI[-1] &
   stockI[-nrow(df1)]) & stockI) | (stockI & stockII)))
#[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Just one clarification. If I have more than 2 columns and I would like to combine them to one with the same logic the only I need is to  add their names to this  `| (stockI & stockII & stockIII & price)))`

Comment: @Eracog You can place them in a list and use `Reduce("&", df1)`  The first condition needs to be done separately